# IE8 Google Maps setZoom error

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer-8

I am having trouble getting the setZoom method for Google Maps to work correctly in IE8 on this site: www.savingthedream.org.  The map is supposed to zoom on each pin drop when it is placed, and it is specifically IE8 that is not working.  I panTo the pin drop right before setting the zoom, and it is panning correctly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the parameter is a number and it has a valid value.
You maybe want to check your parameter with typeof and parse it in need.

```
   map.setZoom( parseInt(YOUR_ZOOM_LEVEL) )
```